# How to get all the users on a database with SA access?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am new to SQL database and besides running basic queries I don't know much. Trying to figure out how to get users with `SA` access.

Can anyone guide me through this, will really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest scenario (a user explicitly granted `sysadmin` directly) is covered by the following query:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM sys.server_principals AS p
  INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members AS m
  ON p.principal_id = m.member_principal_id
  WHERE m.role_principal_id = 3;
```

But then you may also have users who are members of a Windows group (which SQL Server won't know about) and that group has been granted `sysadmin`. To get all of those users you may need to run some queries against Active Directory (or ask someone who can).

Comment: Your query will list the user with roles but can how to add the type /permission / rights given to the roles

Answer (score 1):

Nobody suggested IS_SRVROLEMEMBER, so here's a third option. Same aspects applies as what Aaron mentioned.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals AS p WHERE IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', p.name) = 1
```

Comment: yea that was the first query I tried but how to add roles along with the give permission to those roles?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add roles" and "with the permission to those roles". A server role can have another server role, but a you cannot have a role being sysadmin (except the real sysadmin role). Trying to add a role as member to the sysadmin role give you the error "You may not add a role to Sysadmin.". (And, btw, IS_SRVROLEMEMBER does not cover the GRANT CONTROL SERVER permission which is very close to sysadmin...)

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give the logins and windows groups with sa permissions on a server.

```
SELECT name,isntname, isntgroup, isntuser
  FROM master.sys.syslogins 
  WHERE sysadmin = 1 
  ORDER BY isntgroup, isntname, isntuser
```

Result set points out the login as windows groups or windows logins as well.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers don't cover the `CONTROL SERVER` privilege, which is similar to sysadmin.

```
SELECT login.name, perm.permission_name, perm.state_desc
FROM sys.server_permissions perm
JOIN sys.server_principals login
ON perm.grantee_principal_id = login.principal_id
WHERE permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER';
```